# laravel - Login with data from REST API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication

Could you please help me because I can not understand how to proceed with the following task. I am building a web app and I have to log in the users in the system via REST API, but I don't know how to proceed.

I am using the basic authentication methods that Laravel offers (php artisan make:auth).

Can you please tell me how and where to implement the logic to log in the users in the system from the REST API?

Comment: I usually use [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) personal access tokens.

Comment: If that's all you know then this is no easy task for you. The basic laravel auth scaffolding is for the web. For api you need to setup api routes and validate users appropriately. Laravel comes built in with token based authentication for api. This makes it simpler, but you need to know the basic api authentication workflow.

Comment: @Sandeesh , can you tell me where I can read more about basic api authentication?

Comment: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/api-token-authentication-laravel-5-2/
https://andrew.cool/blog/64/How-to-use-API-tokens-for-authentication-in-Laravel-5-2

Most preferred but might be overwhelming for starters.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: Is your REST API hooked up to the database you're using with laravel?

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth, the situation is as following:
there is LDAP database I do not have access to it. In the mentioned database there is test users with username(email) and password and I have to use the user credentials to log in my system via the REST API and unfortunatelly I still do not know, how to do it...